# Any tool to sketch layout?

Tags: website-design

Is there any kind of tool to sketch the layout of website roughly? For example just to draw a basic sketch of the design to show others? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you are looking for wireframe software. Here's a list of some to check out:

- [Lovely Charts](http://www.lovelycharts.com/) (free)
- [Pencil Project](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx) (free)
- [Serena Prototype Composer](http://www.serena.com/products/prototype-composer/index.html) (free)
- [MockFlow](http://www.mockflow.com/)
- [Axure RP](http://www.axure.com/)
- [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)
- [HotGloo](http://www.hotgloo.com/)
- [Mockingbird](http://gomockingbird.com/)
- [ProtoShare](http://www.protoshare.com/)
- [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/)
- [Justinmind Prototyper](http://www.justinmind.com/)
- [JumpChart](http://www.jumpchart.com/)
- [Pidoco](https://pidoco.com/en)
- [iPlotz](http://iplotz.com/)

Answer (score 7):

Despite how simple and effective [paper sketches](http://www.geekchix.org/blog/2010/01/03/a-collection-of-printable-sketch-templates-and-sketch-books-for-wireframing/) can be, [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) has a great reputation for doing just what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[MockFlow](http://www.mockflow.com/) is a wireframing tool similar in function to Balsamiq from @dmsnell's answer, but without the literal "sketch" look, which not everyone is fond of.