# Website Layout Design

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any tool to sketch layout?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16186/any-tool-to-sketch-layout)

We use Visio for UML Diagrams / Flow chart Diagrams.

We are actually looking for a Software like Visio, on which we can design the structure of Website Layout and view it before you actually start the POC / Development.

Is there any software like visio, can help us to design a website layout for presentation ?

Comment: http://www.hotgloo.com/

Comment: thank you @Jawad , let me try and respond back to you !!

Comment: hotgloo.com is a paid version !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many options; check which suits you best. Here's a [roundup on Mashable](http://mashable.com/2010/07/15/wireframing-tools/).

Comment: thank you @Ajinkya, Please give me sometime to study about your link !!

Comment: Which product do you recommend whould be the best for me to go for wireframing !!

Comment: I checked mockingbird ..!! Problem with these wireframe websites .. are they are not Tool like Visio which you can download and design it and take it as presentation. On these wireframe websites ( free version ), we have to design it on their website .. !!

Comment: @Check:Give a try to Pencil project. Its completely free http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Downloads/Application.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Axure RP](http://www.axure.com/) is very popular among the larger web design agencies. Although I've never used it myself (due to it's high price) it's high on my wanted list of wireframing software.

Comment: Thank you but this is just a startup project on its beginning phase !! I prefer some tool on free version.